# NEON intrinsic vs c++

Tags: c++, image-processing, assembly, arm, neon

i'm trying to beat the **Gcc** compiler in **ARM**, i expended many time but it seems if i compile the code that i have written with **-o3** flag is faster than using **NEON intrinsic** in my code.
in fact this code is a **gaussianBlur** filter with c++ code:

```
inline void GaussianBlur_5x5_row(const float __restrict_arr *in, float __restrict_arr *out, const unsigned int cols)
{
    //Left columns
    out[0] = (in[0]+in[2])*0.054488685f + (in[0]+in[1])*0.24420135f + in[0]*0.40261996f;
    out[1] = (in[0]+in[3])*0.054488685f + (in[0]+in[2])*0.24420135f + in[1]*0.40261996f;

    //Middle columns (Tiled)
    for (unsigned int j=2; j<cols-2; j+=2)
    {
        out[j  ] = (in[j-2]+in[j+2])*0.054488685f + (in[j-1]+in[j+1])*0.24420135f + in[j  ]*0.40261996f;
        out[j+1] = (in[j-1]+in[j+3])*0.054488685f + (in[j  ]+in[j+2])*0.24420135f + in[j+1]*0.40261996f;


    }
    //Right columns
    out[cols-2] = (in[cols-4]+in[cols-1])*0.054488685f + (in[cols-3]+in[cols-1])*0.24420135f + in[cols-2]*0.40261996f;
    out[cols-1] = (in[cols-3]+in[cols-1])*0.054488685f + (in[cols-2]+in[cols-1])*0.24420135f + in[cols-1]*0.40261996f;
}



void GaussianBlur_5x5(const Matrixf &input, Matrixf &output)
{
    //sigma is 1.0f
    //kernels previously calculated from MATLAB code
    //border type is replicate

    const unsigned int rows = input.rows;
    const unsigned int cols = input.cols;

    output.resize(rows, cols);

    float buffer[cols] __attribute__((aligned(16)));

    //Top rows
    #pragma omp parallel for private(buffer)
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<cols; j++)
            buffer[j] = (input.val[0][j]+input.val[i+2][j])*0.054488685f + (input.val[0][j]+input.val[i+1][j])*0.24420135f + input.val[i][j]*0.40261996f;

        GaussianBlur_5x5_row(buffer, output.val[i], cols);
    }

    //Middle rows
    #pragma omp parallel for private(buffer) schedule(runtime)
    for (unsigned int i=2; i<rows-2; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<cols; j++)
            buffer[j] = (input.val[i-2][j]+input.val[i+2][j])*0.054488685f + (input.val[i-1][j]+input.val[i+1][j])*0.24420135f + input.val[i][j]*0.40261996f;

        GaussianBlur_5x5_row(buffer, output.val[i], cols);
    }

    //Bottom rows
    #pragma omp parallel for private(buffer)
    for (unsigned int i=rows-2; i<rows; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<cols; j++)
            buffer[j] = (input.val[i-2][j]+input.val[rows-1][j])*0.054488685f + (input.val[i-1][j]+input.val[rows-1][j])*0.24420135f + input.val[i][j]*0.40261996f;

        GaussianBlur_5x5_row(buffer, output.val[i], cols);
    }
}
```

and in the following code i'm using NEON intrinsic:

```
#include <arm_neon.h>

inline void GaussianBlur5x5_row_rc( const float __restrict_arr *in, float __restrict_arr *out, const unsigned int cols)
{
    //Left columns
    out[0] = (in[0]+in[2])*0.054488685f + (in[0]+in[1])*0.24420135f + in[0]*0.40261996f;
    out[1] = (in[0]+in[3])*0.054488685f + (in[0]+in[2])*0.24420135f + in[1]*0.40261996f;


     const float32x4_t coef_1 = { 0.054488685f , 0.122100675f , 0.20130998f , 0.122100675f };
     const float32x4_t coef_2 = { 0.122100675f , 0.20130998f  , 0.122100675f, 0.054488685f };



    //Middle columns
    for (unsigned int j=2; j<cols-2; j+=2)
    {

        out[j  ] = (in[j-2]+in[j+2])*0.054488685f + (in[j-1]+in[j+1])*0.24420135f + in[j  ]*0.40261996f;
        out[j+1] = (in[j-1]+in[j+3])*0.054488685f + (in[j  ]+in[j+2])*0.24420135f + in[j+1]*0.40261996f

    }
    //Right columns
    out[cols-2] = (in[cols-4]+in[cols-1])*0.054488685f + (in[cols-3]+in[cols-1])*0.24420135f + in[cols-2]*0.40261996f;
    out[cols-1] = (in[cols-3]+in[cols-1])*0.054488685f + (in[cols-2]+in[cols-1])*0.24420135f + in[cols-1]*0.40261996f;
}


void GaussianBlur5x5_NEON_rc( const Matrixf &input, Matrixf &output)
{
    //sigma is 1.0f
    //kernels previously calculated from MATLAB code
    //border type is replicate

    const unsigned int rows = input.rows;
    const unsigned int cols = input.cols;

    output.resize(rows, cols);

    float buffer[cols] __attribute__((aligned(16)));

    //Top rows
    #pragma omp parallel for private(buffer)

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<cols; j++)
            buffer[j] = (input.val[0][j]+input.val[i+2][j])*0.054488685f + (input.val[0][j]+input.val[i+1][j])*0.24420135f + input.val[i][j]*0.40261996f;

        GaussianBlur5x5_row_rc(buffer, output.val[i], cols);
    }



    const float32x4_t a0 = {0.054488685f , 0.054488685f , 0.054488685f ,0.054488685f };
    const float32x4_t a1 = {0.24420135f  , 0.24420135f  ,  0.24420135f ,0.24420135f  };
    const float32x4_t a2 = {0.40261996f  , 0.40261996f  ,  0.40261996f ,0.40261996f  };


    //Middle rows
    //#pragma omp parallel for private(buffer) schedule(runtime)
    for (unsigned int i=2; i<rows-2; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<cols; j+=4)
        {
            float32x4_t row_0 = vld1q_f32( &input.val[i-2][j] );
            float32x4_t row_1 = vld1q_f32( &input.val[i-1][j] );
            float32x4_t row_2 = vld1q_f32( &input.val[i  ][j] );
            float32x4_t row_3 = vld1q_f32( &input.val[i+1][j] );
            float32x4_t row_4 = vld1q_f32( &input.val[i+2][j] );


            float32x4_t h_0 = vaddq_f32( row_4 , row_0 );                   ///// vmlaq
            float32x4_t h_1 = vaddq_f32( row_3 , row_1 );
            float32x4_t h_2 = vmulq_f32( h_0   , a0    );

                        h_0 = vmlaq_f32( h_2   , h_1  , a1 );
                        h_1 = vmlaq_f32( h_0   , row_2, a2 );

            vst1q_f32( &buffer[j] , h_1 );

        }
        GaussianBlur5x5_row_rc(buffer, output.val[i], cols);
    }

    //Bottom rows
    #pragma omp parallel for private(buffer)
    for (unsigned int i=rows-2; i<rows; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<cols; j++)
            buffer[j] = (input.val[i-2][j]+input.val[rows-1][j])*0.054488685f + (input.val[i-1][j]+input.val[rows-1][j])*0.24420135f + input.val[i][j]*0.40261996f;

        GaussianBlur5x5_row_rc(buffer, output.val[i], cols);
    }
}
```

then i decided to use inline assembly but the result of code was far slower than other code

```
inline void GaussianBlur_5x5_row_asm(const float __restrict_arr *in, float __restrict_arr *out, const unsigned int cols)
{
    //Left columns
    out[0] = (in[0]+in[2])*0.054488685f + (in[0]+in[1])*0.24420135f + in[0]*0.40261996f;
    out[1] = (in[0]+in[3])*0.054488685f + (in[0]+in[2])*0.24420135f + in[1]*0.40261996f;


    const float c1[4] = { 0.054488685f , 0.122100675f , 0.20130998f , 0.122100675f };
    const float c2[4] = { 0.122100675f , 0.20130998f  , 0.122100675f, 0.054488685f };

    //Middle columns (Tiled)
    for (unsigned int j=2; j<cols-2; j+=2)
    {
    asm volatile(
                "mov r0, %[co1];"
                "mov r1, %[co2];"
                "mov r2, %[in_j_n2];"
                "mov r3, %[in_j_n1];"
                "mov r4, %[in_j];"

                "vld1.32 {d0,d1}, [r0];"                    // q0 = c1
                "vld1.32 {d2,d3}, [r1];"                    // q1 = c2
                "vld1.32 {d4,d5}, [r2];"                    // q2 = in[j-2]
                "vld1.32 {d6,d7}, [r3];"                    // q3 = in[j-1]
                "vld1.32 {d8,d9}, [r4];"                    // q4 = in[j]

                "vmul.f32 q5, q2, q0;"
                "vmul.f32 q6, q3, q1;"
                "vadd.f32 q7, q6, q5;"
                "vadd.f32 d16, d15, d14;"
                "vpadd.f32 d17, d16, d16;"               // out[j]

                "vmul.f32 q5, q3, q0;"
                "vmul.f32 q6, q4, q1;"
                "vadd.f32 q7, q6, q5;"
                "vadd.f32 d18, d15, d14;"
                "vpadd.f32 d19, d18, d18;"               // out[j+1]

                "mov r5, %[out_j];"
                "mov r6, %[out_j_p1];"
                "vst1.32 d17[0], [r5];"
                "vst1.32 d19[0], [r6];"

                :
                :[co1] "r" (c1) , [co2] "r" (c2) , [in_j_n2] "r" (&in[j-2]) , [in_j_n1] "r" (&in[j-1]) , [in_j] "r" (&in[j]) ,[out_j] "r" (&out[j]) , [out_j_p1] "r" (&out[j+1])
                :"r0","r1","r2","r3"//,"q0","q1","q2","q3","q4","q5","q6","q7","d16","d17","q5","q6","q7","d18","d19","r5","r6"
                );

    }
    //Right columns
    out[cols-2] = (in[cols-4]+in[cols-1])*0.054488685f + (in[cols-3]+in[cols-1])*0.24420135f + in[cols-2]*0.40261996f;
    out[cols-1] = (in[cols-3]+in[cols-1])*0.054488685f + (in[cols-2]+in[cols-1])*0.24420135f + in[cols-1]*0.40261996f;
}



void GaussianBlur_5x5_asm(const Matrixf &input, Matrixf &output)
{
    //sigma is 1.0f
    //kernels previously calculated from MATLAB code
    //border type is replicate

    const unsigned int rows = input.rows;
    const unsigned int cols = input.cols;

    output.resize(rows, cols);

    float buffer[cols] __attribute__((aligned(16)));

    //Top rows
    #pragma omp parallel for private(buffer)
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<cols; j++)
        {
            buffer[j] = (input.val[0][j]+input.val[i+2][j])*0.054488685f + (input.val[0][j]+input.val[i+1][j])*0.24420135f + input.val[i][j]*0.40261996f;
        }
        GaussianBlur_5x5_row_asm(buffer, output.val[i], cols);
    }

    const float a0[4] = {0.054488685f , 0.054488685f , 0.054488685f , 0.054488685f};
    const float a1[4] = {0.24420135f  , 0.24420135f  , 0.24420135f  , 0.24420135f };
    const float a2[4] = {0.40261996f  , 0.40261996f  , 0.40261996f  , 0.40261996f };



    //Middle rows
    //#pragma omp parallel for private(buffer) schedule(runtime)
    for (unsigned int i=2; i<rows-2; i++)
    {
    for (unsigned int j=0; j<cols; j+=4)
    {
        //  buffer[j] = (input.val[i-2][j]+input.val[i+2][j])*0.054488685f + (input.val[i-1][j]+input.val[i+1][j])*0.24420135f + input.val[i][j]*0.40261996f;

        asm volatile(
                    "mov r0, %[c0];"
                    "mov r1, %[c1];"
                    "mov r2, %[c2];"

                    "mov r3, %[in_0];"
                    "mov r4, %[in_1];"
                    "mov r5, %[in_2];"
                    "mov r6, %[in_3];"
                    "mov r7, %[in_4];"

                    "vld1.32 {d0 , d1}, [r0];"    //  q0 = a0
                    "vld1.32 {d2 , d3}, [r1];"    //  q1 = a1
                    "vld1.32 {d4 , d5}, [r2];"    //  q2 = a2
                    "vld1.32 {d6 , d7}, [r3];"    //  q3 = input.val[i-2]
                    "vld1.32 {d8 , d9}, [r4];"    //  q4 = input.val[i-1]
                    "vld1.32 {d10,d11}, [r5];"    //  q5 = input.val[i  ]
                    "vld1.32 {d12,d13}, [r6];"    //  q6 = input.val[i+1]
                    "vld1.32 {d14,d15}, [r7];"    //  q7 = input.val[i+2]

                    "vmul.f32 q8 , q3, q0;"
                    "vmul.f32 q9 , q4, q1;"
                    "vmul.f32 q10, q5, q2;"
                    "vmul.f32 q11, q6, q1;"
                    "vmul.f32 q12, q7, q0;"

                    "vadd.f32 q0, q9 , q8 ;"
                    "vadd.f32 q1, q10, q11;"
                    "vadd.f32 q2, q1 , q0 ;"
                    "vadd.f32 q3, q12, q2 ;"         // final

                    "mov r8, %[out_buffer];"
                    "vst1.32 {d6,d7}, [r8];"
                    :
                    :[c0]"r"(a0) , [c1]"r"(a1) , [c2]"r"(a2) ,
                     [in_0]"r"(&input.val[i-2][j]) , [in_1]"r"(&input.val[i-1][j]) , [in_2]"r"(&input.val[i][j]) , [in_3]"r"(&input.val[i+1][j]) , [in_4]"r"(&input.val[i+2][j]) ,
                     [out_buffer]"r"(&buffer[j])
                    :"r0","r1","r2","r3"
                    );
    }
    GaussianBlur_5x5_row_asm(buffer, output.val[i], cols);
    }

    //Bottom rows
    //#pragma omp parallel for private(buffer)
    for (unsigned int i=rows-2; i<rows; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<cols; j++)
            buffer[j] = (input.val[i-2][j]+input.val[rows-1][j])*0.054488685f + (input.val[i-1][j]+input.val[rows-1][j])*0.24420135f + input.val[i][j]*0.40261996f;

        GaussianBlur_5x5_row_asm(buffer, output.val[i], cols);
    }
}
```

does it possible beat the GCC compiler if it use -o3 flag?

Comment: Well, did you benchmark it?

Comment: Reminder:  NEON is a coprocessor.  Sending instructions to the coprocessor and waiting for result, may take longer than pipelined instructions on the primary core.

Comment: You may be able to speed up your code by assigning constants to constant variables.  This may allow the compiler to keep the constants in registers rather than reloading from executable area each time.

Comment: of course i benchmarked. run time for  cpp  is 5.5 ms and neon intrinsic's  is 7 ms and with inline assembly i measured 20 ms

Comment: Have you looked at the assembly generated by compiling the C++? If it's beating you by a factor of 4, it's doing something right. Also, do you have a reason to do this other than experimenting? Compilers are wonderful tools that can, in many cases, generate more efficient code than a human can, for larger chunks of code.

Comment: The compiler will use SIMD instructions and all sorts of tricks that it can figure out. Hand-crafted assembly is guaranteed slower if you don’t know how to apply all those tricks. Plus, it’s harder to read and harder to maintain.

Comment: If you are coding in assembler, `mov` is an admission of failure.  The compiler will arrange registers to absolutely minimize `mov` instructions.  It is quite possible that the gcc is already using NEON for the loop.  You should look with `objdump -S -d` and see if it is using NEON.  Given enough time, a human can beat a compiler.  The question is 'is it worth it?'.  If the compiler figures out how not to reload memory, it will beat you because video/image is often memory bound.  You seem to reload the original pixel several times as the value is used for itself and neighbors.